# Git pull doesn't update changes

Tags: git, pull

I use only one branch `master`.

I wrote a new method and then committed and pushed it.Then I accidentally removed the method from my local branch.
[image]
When i try to get back the method from remote branch to local by git pull using intellij IDE there is no merge option and a message appears: All files are up-to-date

Comment: On pull command what message are you getting?

Comment: All files are up-to-date

Comment: Can you share your screenshot of git pull? To help you better?

Comment: Be aware that IDEs like IntelliJ *are not Git*. They may *use* Git, but they'll sometimes change the behaviors and/or messages of various operations. Git itself never says "All files are up-to-date"; its message here would be `Already up to date.` There's no word about *files* here, which is important: Git is saying that your *commits* are up to date. (Git is about *commits*, not files.)

Answer (score 3):

You can **reset** *local branch* to what's at remote

`git reset --hard origin/master`

Comment: Thanks.But why do i a message:"All files are up-to-date"?

Answer (score 3):

`git pull` doesn't update the changes, because `git pull` updates according to new changes in the remote, so when you deleted the file, its deleted in your local, and there is no new change in the remote. When you `git pull` there is no new change/commit in remote it doesn't change anything and showed "All files are up-to-date".

In your case
`git reset --hard origin/master` will get back your deleted file, as this command will reset your local to the remote.

Comment: Thanks.What if i already wrote a few new methods in local and don't want to reset local to remote,but only to merge changes? Is there a command for it?

Comment: If you want to recover only your deleted file and also not want to lose other local changes, you can git checkout -- <path_to_deleted_file> to recover that. Also if you feel my answer was satisfactory you can accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Git's way of undoing local changes (which you have not committed yet) is `checkout`:

```sh
git checkout -- <file>
```

will discard all uncommitted changes to `<file>` in your working copy.

If you want to discard only some of the changes, use `-p`:

```sh
git checkout -p -- <file>
```

and git will ask you for each hunk whether you want to discard it or not.

The above commands are for the command line (*git bash* if you are under Windows).

Since you are using the IntelliJ IDE, you may also want to consult the local history maintained by IntelliJ - this is independent of git and should allow you to return to a previous version of any file.